# Learning Digital Signal Processing

Tags: signal-processing

What are some good resources for learning about DSP (including the mathematics and algorithms necessary for actually *understanding* these resources)?

Let's assume that my math skills are rusty from lack of use as well, so a roadmap along the lines of:

- Stats refresher
- Calculus refresher
- Solid newbie explanation of [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFT) 
   
  (50 steps later...)

would be nice and hopefully result in DSP skills and knowledge approaching "competent".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[How Do I Learn DSP?](http://www.redcedar.com/learndsp.htm)

[A Beginner's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/landing-pages/001/beginners-guide-to-dsp.html)

As well as the [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing
By Steven W. Smith](http://www.dspguide.com/eightres.htm), there is also the excellent [Understanding Digital Signal Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634678)

Answer (score 8):

I learned a lot from the Scientist and Engineer's Guide to DSP. You can read it for free online at http://www.dspguide.com/  It's nice because it focuses more on what you can do with DSP, rather than the underlying math.