# gcc-linux-gnueabi-arm error undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c, gcc, linker, neon

I am trying to generate assembly and executable of a simple neon-based c code. The code is,

```
  #include <arm_neon.h>
  void NeonTest(short int * __restrict a, short int * __restrict b, short int * __restrict z)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
z[i] = a[i] * b[i];
            }
}
```

First, I am going for the assembly to calculate the neon instructions,

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -S neon_test.c -o nt.s
```

Then I am converting the nt.s file to object file.

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -c nt.s -o nt.o
```

Finally, for the executable I do,

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon nt.o -o nt
```

I get the error,

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using Ubuntu 14LTS on Intel system.

Comment: As the error says it all: There is no function called `main()` in your program. Check this on why main is required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264367/why-is-main-necessary-in-a-program

Comment: @SantoshA thanks the problem is solved in including a main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every program needs a starting point so the computer knows where to begin execution. In C/C++, the starting point is the beginning of the function `int main`. Give your program an `int main` by either linking your object file to an object file with `int main`, or adding one in this code.

To add main in your code, beneath your function definition, try

```
int main()
{
    NeonTest(/* your parameters */);
}
```

Comment: thanks the problem is solved in including a main function.

Answer (score 2):

You're not including the C file that contains main() when compiling, so the linker isn't seeing it
You need to add it:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon nt.o main.o -o nt
```

where main.o is also created following the same step as neon.o