# C++ library for drawing graphics

Tags: c++, math, graphics, drawing, 2d

Someone can suggest me a good, free, easy to use library for c++ that allow to draw a mathematical function in a window for microsoft windows? (e.g. the parabola x^2+5x+3=0)

Comment: i need something like the TChart component of C++ Builder (rad studio) in terms of the usage semplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another wxWidgets-based option is [wxArt2D](http://www.wxart2d.org/), It has got tons of good features for drawing mathematical functions as curves, like you could easily pass this **y=140*cos(x/20) + 80*cos(x*2/20) + 40*cos(x*4/20)"** to a curve object and it will get drawn, it's amazing!
Check out these [screenshots](http://wxart2d.org/moin/WxArt2dScreenShots) there are some curves drawn by equations in *string* format!

Comment: Is the double quote at the end of your example formula a second-derivative operator or just a closing double quote?

Answer (score 15):

Since you need a ready-made plotting widget, use [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/).

It uses Qt.

You could use Qt directly as in contero's answer, without Qwt, as the task is simple enough. However, Qwt has lots of graph features built in, and the usage is straightforward.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 5):

Another option is [wxMathPlot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net/) which is [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) based.
From it's website:
wxMathPlot main features:

- Completely mouse-driven view control: pan, zoom, scroll, box
  positioning.
- Printing class.
- Screenshot saving of plot window (BMP, PNG and JPEG formats).
- Overlay movable boxes with legend or mouse coordinate display.
- Can set margins to avoid plots to cover axis labels.
- Flexible axis positioning
- A series of useful layer to directly plot data from STL vector, movable objects, covariance ellipse,  bitmaps, etc.
- Multi-platform: runs everywhere wxWidgets does.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a program similar to this using Qt. Qt is wonderful once you get it set up, but it may take a bit of effort if you've never used it (as will OpenGL, DirectX, etc..).

You can create a [QImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html) and set it to whatever background color you want, then run your program through the width of the image pixel by pixel calling your function to get the y value. Roughly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) {
   image->setPixel(i, yourFunction(i), lineColor);
}
```

Once you've created your QImage, you can attach it to a [QLabel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html) using setPixmap(). Once you've attached it you can then display the image in a layout.

Answer (score 1):

You mention your language (C++) and platform (Windows), but there are frameworks available for writing a Windows C++ application: Qt, MFC, C++Builder...  Additionally, C and C++ can interface with just about anything.  So your decision for which plotting library to use will depend on what framework you're using for your UI and on what kind of external interfaces or dependencies you're willing to introduce:

- If you're using **Qt**, you should use [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/), as [Stefan Monov said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095536/c-library-for-drawing-graphics/5126689#5126689).
- If you're using **C++Builder**, you should try [TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/teechart/vcl) or [TMS Advanced Charts](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advchart.asp).
- For **wxWidgets**, try [wxMathPlot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net/) or [wxArt2D](http://www.wxart2d.org/), recommended by [Eugen Constantin Dinca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095536/c-library-for-drawing-graphics/5150951#5150951) and [Parsa Jamshidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095536/c-library-for-drawing-graphics/5179631#5179631).
- If you don't mind calling **an external program** to do your plotting, then [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a popular and powerful solution.  [C and C++ libraries exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275484/good-plotting-library-for-c) to simplify calling Gnuplot.
- If you're willing to **embed Python**, then [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is very popular, and Python could simplify the development of some of your charts.
- For an **atypical solution**, you could have your C++ library generate a [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) web page then point an embedded web browser at it.
- For a **framework-independent C or C++ library** with no external dependencies, the most promising solution I've found is [PLplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/download.php), although I haven't yet had a chance to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDI/+, OpenGL, Direct3D, Direct2D as well if you're using Vista/7. There's plenty out there.

Comment: I mean some library done on that purpose, that would allow me  to draw a graph of a function with a few easy steps

Answer (score 0):

Definitely gnuplot, and the library gnuplot++

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool to plot graphics and published it several hours ago.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xD080qQVaD8&feature=youtu.be

https://github.com/burlachenkok/plotter_plusplus

To use this tool you can use desktop computer to show graphics.

Your target project can be run anywhere in any language in any platform - to update graphics just send data over the network.