# what's the best way to draw statisitics charts in QT

Tags: qt

I'd like to draw some statistics charts using QT4.7 ,

here are some examples:
[example pictures](http://processtrends.com/toc_statistical_charts.htm)

what's the best way to do that?

Comment: sorry for reply late, I am using c++ .

Comment: just for the people who looking for answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095536/c-library-for-drawing-graphics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "best" way, but out of my personal experience i recommend [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). Consistent documentation is generally something to desire (basically doxygen only), but it is open source and IMHO clean and understandable internal design. The license is a loosened LGPL.