# draw chart in Qwidget

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I want to draw a simple line chart in my QWidget application. I found [this link](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/), but when I add `

```
#QT += charts
```

to my .pro file, an error appear that :

> Unknown module(s) in QT: charts

Comment: As you can see at the bottom of the linked page, the module is available only under certain Qt licenses

Comment: @Fabio Is there any other simple and free component or other thing to draw chart in qt?

Comment: Try [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Qtw is too heavy. Try `QCustomPlot`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the best way to draw statisitics charts in QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084372/whats-the-best-way-to-draw-statisitics-charts-in-qt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/). It's free (GPL), simple (just 2 files), fast and well-documented.

Comment: GPL can be a limiting factor for some applications. Alternatively Qwt is available under LGPL, which allows closed-source dynamic linking.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Qt Charts (it is free, [qt blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/13/new-agreement-with-the-kde-free-qt-foundation/)), but you need cloning git repository and building the project manually. Git repository you can find [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtcharts.git/).

Comment: It's free only from Qt 5.7. It is now only in alpha version.