# Graphing Functions in C

Tags: c, function, trigonometry

Is there any library in C, that let me graph functions like sin, cos, tan, log, ln, exp.

Or which is the best way to do it?. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275484/good-plotting-library-for-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used gnuplot with C before. It should satisfy what you are trying to do.

[See here for information about gnuplot and C.](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a library called `EzWindows` a while back, you can search it on google.
There are also more advanced libraries like SDL or SFML for easy graphical design but I'm not sure if there is strictly a function to draw a graph alone.

Other then that I don't know about any other library strictly for math graphs, but you can always try making WinApi and draw it yourself.