# Math Functions graph in c

Tags: c

I'm new here, I searched for any related post like my question and I found nothing
I have a project to create a math function graph in a console like f(x)=ax^2+bx+c the user give me a b c and I draw the function.
Someone told me that there are a library called graphic.h that help me with that 
so if someone can help me, I'm not finding anything about graphic.h and my project 
And if there are another library or anything that could help 
Thanks

Comment: Do you know something about Gnuplot ? It might help you.

Comment: Perhaps something from here would help you (You mentioned something about graphic.h so I guess you want some C API): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275484/good-plotting-library-for-c

Comment: Stack overflow does not consider questions like this to be on topic because the help you're asking for is extremely broad. Your questions here need to be concise and be able to be answered with concise responses. That is... _you_ choose your library, get started, and ask for help with specific issues rather than non-specific "how do I get started?" type things.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow
and I'm not asking on how to start 
I'm asking is there a better library then graphic.h for my project

Comment: I saw a library called mathGL does that works for me ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do graphs, I prefer WinApi but it's not the simplest because you need to learn about C for windows first and then use WM_PAINT command to draw a line for every few pixels to draw something like that, for simple f(x) = ax + b you can just use a single line function but as I said it's not the simplest way. There are libraries like conio.h and graphics.h but never used them for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for incomplete answer but you have incomplete question so it is impossible to answer ...

What environment you have to use ? You wrote console **but what compiler and OS ?** because graphics is very different for each

1. **DOS**

   many schools still use **DOS console apps**  which is not the same as win or linux console. In **DOS** there is **graphics.h** which switch to gfx video mode and then you can use **CGA/EGA/VGA** and sometimes **VESA** graphics. Haven't done anything in it since Turbo Pascal 7.0 few decades ago.

   for **DOS** I am using **direct VGA/VESA access** instead (works on **win32** too) but anyway look [here](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/graphics.h) and [here](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/) for info about `graphics.h` with examples.

   `graphics.h` stands for **BGI** (Borland Graphics Interface) but you need **CGA/EGA/VGA** or **VESA** for proper functionality. Most gfx cards emulate them so that should be no problem just do not expect any arbitrary pixel or color resolution. It can handle 640x480x16 or 320x200x256 and the rest depends on your **HW**. This lib is native only to ancient **Borland/Embarcadero compilers** so you will find it somewhere in include path so use `< >` not `" "` !!! (you do not need to copy it to your project).

   ```
   #include <graphics.h>
   ```
2. **Windows**

   You have to create **graphics window** by **WinApi** or by **IDE** of your programing language and then you can use **GDI** which is part of **WinAPI** and most compilers have libs for it natively.
3. **linux or different GUI OS**

   I do not code for such so I do not know exactly but should be similar to Windows
4. **OpenGL (any GUI OS and also sometimes DOS with proper drivers)**

   if you use **OpenGL** then you can find tons of examples how to create gfx window + OpenGL and also OpenGL GLUT (OpenGL  utilities) have functions that take care of windows stuff. You just code code for events like keystroke, mouse move, redraw ...

   google **NeHe OpenGL tutorials** ... not my favorite but beginners like it

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214) for some more info

**Now for the function plot**

1. **clear gfx screen**
2. **create for loop from `xmin` to `xmax`**
3. **compute `y` value for each `x`**

   do not forget to scale and offset `x,y` values to fit your gfx area !!!
4. **draw line from previous to actual point**

   with different color than clear ...