# Implementation of pow function in c language with power of -3/2 or -5/2

Tags: c, infinite-loop, pow, divide-by-zero

I am new to C language. I am trying to implement the formula `(r to power of (-3/2)) * exp(t*(r-1/r)`. I am using `pow` function but when I keep this equation in for loop it continuously implementing the loop saying that `"pow domain error"`. I want the increment in for loop to be of `0.2`. Please help me in implementing this formula. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    double R,r;
    float f;
    clrscr();
    for(r=0;r<=5;r+0.2)
    {
        R=pow(r,-1.5)*exp(2.5*(r-1)/r);
        f=r-R;
        printf("value of f is:%f",f);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is `r+0.2` - should be `r+=0.2`

Comment: Change `for(r=0;r<=5;r+0.2)` to `for(r=1;r<=5;r+=0.2)`. (The computation of `pow(r,-1.5)` and `(r-1)/r` will fail when r = 0.)

Comment: Your loop `for(r=0;r<=5;r+=0.2)` will end with iteration in which `r` is approximately 4.8; it will not execute an iteration `r` is 5 (or approximately 5). This is in part because when .2 is converted to the floating-point format common C implementations use, the result is 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. To iterate properly, use `for (double i = 0; i <= 50; i += 2)` and put `r = i / 10;` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to be aware that:

The C Standard, `7.12.1 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011]`, defines three types of errors that relate specifically to math functions in .  Paragraph 2 states

> A **domain error** occurs if an input argument is **outside the domain** over
>   which the mathematical function is defined.

Paragraph 3 states

> A pole error (also known as a singularity or infinitary) occurs if the
>   mathematical function has an exact infinite result as the finite input
>   argument(s) are approached in the limit.

Paragraph 4 states

> A range error occurs if the mathematical result of the function cannot
>   be represented in an object of the specified type, due to extreme
>   magnitude.

The available **domain** for function **`pow(x,y)`** is:

```
 (x > 0) || (x == 0 && y > 0) || (x < 0 && y is an integer)
```

Which means that you cannot use `r = 0` as an argument of `pow`.

1) 
   `pow(r, -1.5) =  r^(-3/2) = 1.0/ r^3/2  = 1.0/sqrt(r*r*r);`

2) In C language
`main` function should return `int` value and takes `void` not empty bracket `()`

3) Incrementing operation can be done via `r = r + 0.2` or `r += 0.2`

4) To avoid division by zero in `(r-1)/r` close to `0` value has to be used instead.

5) In order to not loose `double` precision the variable `f` should be also declared `double`.

6) The value of `f` for `r=0` is extremely difficult to calculate. The algorithm is numerically unstable for `r = 0`. We have division  of two infinities. The proper way to solve it is to find function limit at point `0+`. Numerically, its is enough to set `r` close to `0`.

[image]

7) You may consider much more smaller step for `r` in order to capture a better plot due to the nature of your `f` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define  ZERO_PLUS      1e-14       

void calculate_and_print(double r)
{
    double f, f1;

    f =  r -       pow(r, -1.5) * exp(2.5*(r-1)/r);
    f1 = r - (1.0 /sqrt(r*r*r)) * exp(2.5*(r-1)/r);

    printf("Value of f for r= %f  is  f= %f  f1= %f \n", r, f, f1);
}

int main(void)
{
    clrscr();

    calculate_and_print(ZERO_PLUS);  

    for (double r = 0.2; r < 5.0; r += 0.2 )
        calculate_and_print(r);

    calculate_and_print(5.0); 

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Value of f for r= 0.000000  is  f= 0.000000  f1= 0.000000                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 0.200000  is  f= 0.199492  f1= 0.199492                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 0.400000  is  f= 0.307038  f1= 0.307038                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 0.600000  is  f= 0.193604  f1= 0.193604                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 0.800000  is  f= 0.051949  f1= 0.051949                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 1.000000  is  f= 0.000000  f1= 0.000000                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 1.200000  is  f= 0.046058  f1= 0.046058                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 1.400000  is  f= 0.166843  f1= 0.166843                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 1.600000  is  f= 0.338256  f1= 0.338256                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 1.800000  is  f= 0.542116  f1= 0.542116                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 2.000000  is  f= 0.765977  f1= 0.765977                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 2.200000  is  f= 1.001644  f1= 1.001644                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 2.400000  is  f= 1.243810  f1= 1.243810                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 2.600000  is  f= 1.489073  f1= 1.489073                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 2.800000  is  f= 1.735278  f1= 1.735278                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 3.000000  is  f= 1.981075  f1= 1.981075                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 3.200000  is  f= 2.225642  f1= 2.225642                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 3.400000  is  f= 2.468498  f1= 2.468498                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 3.600000  is  f= 2.709387  f1= 2.709387                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 3.800000  is  f= 2.948194  f1= 2.948194                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 4.000000  is  f= 3.184898  f1= 3.184898                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 4.200000  is  f= 3.419535  f1= 3.419535                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 4.400000  is  f= 3.652177  f1= 3.652177                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 4.600000  is  f= 3.882916  f1= 3.882916                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 4.800000  is  f= 4.111856  f1= 4.111856                                                                                     
Value of f for r= 5.000000  is  f= 4.339103  f1= 4.339103
```

[image]

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: One can loop with integer values in `double` format. That is, they ought to increment by 2 instead of .2 but may do it in a floating-point type instead of an integer type. Floating-point handles integers exactly, up to the point where they overflow the width available (same as integer formats), and using floating-point instead of integer avoids repeated integer-to-floating-point conversions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are absolutely right! I corrected the answer and increment the double to avoid conversions. I increment by `1.0` in order to avoid division by `10.0`. The multiplication is faster then the division.

Comment: how can we plot the graph between f and r using c language .Is there any function that helps us plotting .

Comment: @SudhirKumar C language does not have any build in plot function.  An external library would have to be used. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275484/good-plotting-library-for-c

Comment: when i am trying to write these values to a file it says the pointer is not defined and just only one values is getting printed to file

Comment: @SudhirKumar I will be happy to review your code. Post it as a separate questions.  Do you need more help with the current question?

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow:

> If base is zero and exp is negative, a domain error or a pole error may occur.

You run into that situation when you evaulate `pow(r, -1.5)` with the value of `r` set to zero.

Change your loop so that `r` starts with 0.2 instead of zero.

Also, you need to use `r += 0.2` instead of `r+0.2` in the `for` statement.

```
for ( r = 0.2; r <= 5; r += 0.2)
{
   R = pow(r, -1.5)*exp(2.5*(r-1)/r);
   f = r-R;
   printf("value of f is:%f", f);
}
```

Comment: once i get the results i should be plotting the graph for r and f.So the initial value that r has to be 0 .

Comment: @SudhirKumar Well, if you can figure out what `pow(0, -1.5)` is, you can then move on to the problem of what `2.5*(0-1)/0` is.